# Jackson: How can I include different properties of a child object for multiple objects which contain that child object as a field

Tags: java, jackson

I have two classes which both encapsulate the same class e.g:

```
class A1 {
  private Child child;
}

class B1 {
  private Child child;
}

class Child {
  private String a;
  private String b;
}
```

Is it possible to configure jackson to serialise only property 'a' from class Child when serialising class A1 and property 'b' from class Child when serialising class B1
e.g:

```
Child child = new Child();
child.setA("a");
child.setB("b");

A1 a1 = new A1();
a1.setChild(child);
B1 b1 = new B1();
b1.setChild(child);
```

desired output when serialising A1:

```
{
   "child": {
     "a": "a",
   }
}
```

desired output when serialising B1:

```
{
   "child": {
     "b": "b",
   }
}
```

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom Serialization implementation extending the `StdSerializer` could do this.

You will have to specify what parameters to serialize when you call the serializer.

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial